# Which one is faster in codeigniter reading value from Session or Pursing value from URL parameter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, url-parameters

In my web app I have to show content depending on user location. As it is not possible to resolve current location in every request I can set it on URL parameter or Store it on session for further requests. But **I am getting confused about which one will be faster? Pursing the location from url parameter? or reading the location from session in every request?**

Comment: Have you tried testing this for yourself?  Also will it make that much of a difference compared to database access etc.?

Comment: I'd say such difference should be completely irrelevant compared to other factors. Instead you should be interested in easy of maintenance and whether the solution is clean and robust. Which is why I would always go with a session based approach if you can. You should depend as little as possible on the client site behavior.

Comment: I haven't tested it my self, I was thinking about using session, but found that more people are using url parameter than session. That made confuse

Answer (score 1):

Getting an information from the URL itself will probably always be faster than sessions since it's available right away in the memory. How faster is it will depend on the storage method of your sessions. Sessions stored in an external database may take a few milliseconds to load, for example.

Testing it locally sequentially will probably yeld the same results for both methods. To get a reliable benchmark you'll need to test it concurrently with hundreds or thousands of requests per second.

Either way, you shouldn't worry about that kind of optimization, just choose the solution that will be easier to maintain. The URL has the added benefit of being scalable and stateless.